# What is the best deep learning architecture for image classification with different intra-class variances?

Tags: deep-learning, image-classification, cnn

I implemented a CNN image classifier with three classes. The samples belonging to the first class have a low variance (patterns and colors are very similar from image to image). The samples from the second class have a higher variance. Finally, the samples from the third class have been obtained by taking samples from the second class and adding a specific pattern in a random location.

What features should I add to a traditional CNN classifier in order to improve the performances, considering that I have a very large dataset (>15K images per class)? Could it be useful to pre-train the network with the two similar classes and then adding the other one?